# Implement HTTP POST method in iphone app

Tags: iphone, http

I want to retrieve data from server using HTTP POST method for my iphone app.I don't have any idea about implementing it.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at this StackOverflow question which deals with posting a file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199446/how-to-upload-an-audio-file-using-http-post-from-iphone

Comment: Use previous link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033129/sending-data-to-web-form-using-post-from-iphone-app/8033239#8033239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use the framework [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). Take a look in the tutorial: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Answer (score 0):

start with `NSURLRequest` and related sample code.